# bcp utility for Microsoft SQL Server ignores odd rows

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am trying to import a bunch of hashes into a SQL DB for testing purposes. The hashes are in the form of a text file looking like the following:

```
hash1
hash2
hash3
hash4
hash5
hash6
```

Now, for some reason, when I run the command `bcp dbo.Table IN "Path\To\Dump.txt" -T -S SERVER\INSTANCE -d DB -c -t \n`  what happens is that every second hash is imported (i.e. `hash2`, `hash4`, and `hash6`). I have no idea why this is happening. Similarly, if I replace the delimiter argument with just `\r` or, `\n\r`, or `\r\n`, 0 rows get imported. Why is this happening?

Comment: this may help: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic508351-149-1.aspx

Comment: Just to confirm: If you run `select count(*) from importtable`, you find only about half the rows are inserted? Don't assume that your select will return data in the same order as your import file.

Comment: Yeah, running that only yields half the rows.

Comment: @NeerajKumar I looked at that but it seems different since that person's skipped fields are all being squashed into another column. In my case, they are just being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I should have been referencing the View representing my hashes column instead of the whole table itself. That fixed things.